# hibernate how to load Transient object?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have registered entity Staff with transient object StaffParam. Of course StaffParam is registered entity too.

In staff table I don't want to alter to add the reference to staff_param table. so in entity Staff I declare transient object StaffParam. But I don't know there is any way to load transient object in hibernate entity.

If it has please guide me how to config my entity.

***NOTE : I use hibernate annotation to declare my entities. Thanks all

Comment: Objects can't be transient, can they?

Comment: `em.find()` is the method used to get an entity by ID.